# How to build dotnet core in Docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-build

Hi I am trying to build my dotnet core 2.1 app using docker. Whenever i create project template default docker file gets generated. This docker file runs fine but whenever I want to upload it to ecr this will not work. So I changed docker file as below.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:44319
EXPOSE 44319
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj", "LocationServicesAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj"
WORKDIR /app/LocationServicesAPI
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "LocationServicesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

Whenever I run using Docker I get the below error.

```
1>Step 9/19 : EXPOSE 44319
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 069a0777f156
1>Step 10/19 : WORKDIR /src
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 6e9768b88723
1>Step 11/19 : COPY ["LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj", "LocationServicesAPI/"]
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 37b9e63b9b97
1>Step 12/19 : RUN dotnet restore "LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj"
1> ---> Using cache
1>Step 13/19 : WORKDIR /app/LocationServicesAPI
1> ---> f505d07f4d8c
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> e03aaf3a0d7d
1>Step 14/19 : COPY . .
1> ---> 20b8bb0d74bd
1>Step 15/19 : RUN dotnet build "LocationServicesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app
1> ---> Running in f04182972995
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1>
1>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.76+g14b0a930a7 for .NET Core
1>MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
1>Switch: LocationServicesAPI.csproj
1>Removing intermediate container f04182972995
1>The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build "LocationServicesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1
1>C:\Users\ngodbole\Documents\MerchWebServices\LocationServicesAPI\LocationServicesAPI\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: Docker command failed with exit code 1.
1>C:\Users\ngodbole\Documents\MerchWebServices\LocationServicesAPI\LocationServicesAPI\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build "LocationServicesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1
1>Done building project "LocationServicesAPI.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Below error I am getting after correcting the path.

```
1> ---> cc58805dac5d
1>Step 14/19 : COPY . .
1> ---> ced094b3788d
1>Step 15/19 : RUN dotnet build LocationServicesAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app
1> ---> Running in 290429a9f4d1
1>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.76+g14b0a930a7 for .NET Core
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1>
1>Switch: LocationServicesAPI.csproj
1>MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
```

I am not able to figure it out. Can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Dockerfile` you are copying the code into the wrong folder:

```
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj", "LocationServicesAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj"

WORKDIR /app/LocationServicesAPI

COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "LocationServicesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

The second `WORKDIR` command needs to be:

```
WORKDIR /src/LocationServicesAPI
```

This will make sure you copy the source code into the same folder as the .csproj

**EDIT**

You need to move the `WORKDIR /src/LocationServicesAPI` to after the `COPY` command so that the `build` command is executed in the same folder as the `.csproj`

```
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj", "LocationServicesAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/LocationServicesAPI

RUN dotnet build "LocationServicesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

Comment: Thanks I missed it. I changed it. But now I started to get some different error. I will post it above.

Comment: @Niranjan do you get any solution??